# Fortran/C program for x86 compilation on Apple Silicon

Tags: c, gfortran, apple-silicon

I am trying to compile a software written in Fortran, which needs also some libraries written in C. The software was originally written to be compiled on x86 linux architecture, but I am trying to compile it on my Mac with Apple Silicon (M1 Max). I was able to modify both the script and the source code in order to remove the vast majority of errors and/or warnings, but I am now stuck with the linking of the libraries using ranlib and ar.

When compiling, the errors generated follow:

```
ar rv mapst.a \*.o

a - ispand.o

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: mapst.a(ispand.o) cputype (16777228) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)

rm -f ispand.o

ranlib mapst.a

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: mapst.a(ispand.o) cputype (16777228) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)
```

As far as I understand, the issue arises with the flag of the compiler. Currently, the makefile has the following flags:

```
FTN = gfortran

FFLAGS = -O3 -Wuninitialized -fno-f2c -fno-automatic -fno-range-check -fno-backslash

CC = /usr/bin/gcc

CFLAGS = -c
```

Adding "-m64" to the gfortran (which, by the way, is the compiler provided with homebrew's gcc) flags, nothing changes, while adding "-arch arm" to the gcc flags, changes the architecture from 16777228 to 12, but in any case the error remains there.

Do you have any advice on how should I modify the Makefile in order to compile the software?

Comment: This is not the problem, but `CFLAGS` shouldn't contain `-c`. Also, not sure why you need the full path for /usr/bin/gcc, but not for gfortran.

Comment: Have you tried removing mapst.a to ensure it is built from scratch?

Comment: If your C compiler or Fortran compiler does not build for the machine's own architecture by default then something is deeply wrong.  Fix this by fixing whichever one(s) of those is not building for the right arch.  That might mean reconfiguring or reinstalling the offending compiler, or even removing it in favor of something different.

Comment: @IanAbbott thank you for your suggestions: of course I am cleaning the source folder each time I try a new compilation, hence the mapst.a file is compiled each time as well. You are right about the full path, since `which gcc` gives me exactly the correct compiler, hence I removed it, while the `-c` flag is needed, otherwise I obtain a `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for pointing out this issue, however, if I get verbose information from both gcc and gfortran compiler, I obtain correct, alas slightly different, information: `gcc -v` returns `Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5) -- Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.1.0` while `gfortran -v` gives, among the others, `Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22`. I fear this is the cause of the issues found.

Comment: Well if your Makefile is using implicit rules, then `CFLAGS` shouldn't contain `-c`. Perhaps your Makefile is only using explicit rules?

Comment: In that case, @Pierdomenico, it might be worth checking whether your source package includes any pre-built object files, such that some of those going into the library were not built with your Apple toolchain at all.  If so, then that might (or might not) be fixed by cleaning out all the object files before building.  Same for packaging existing, non-empty libraries.

Comment: It might also be that the makefile contains a rule for one or more specific targets that causes those to be built for a specific CPU.  Or with a different C or Fortran compiler than you think.  None of the flags presented in the question will have such an effect.  Overall, there is nothing in what you've presented so far that would explain the errors you ask about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I found that the issue was related with the different compiler used for C and Fortran: while gcc comes from xcode, gfortran was installed using brew. As suspected, the issue was related with the libraries compiled for two slightly different architectures by default (**arm64-apple-darwin23.1.0** for gcc and **x86_64-apple-darwin22** for gfortran). I have added the `-target x86_64-apple-darwin22` flag to gcc rules to solve the issue. Thank you to everyone!